# Arabic Content issue in reading mails using javamail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using Javamail API to read mails from Gmail server.  I am sending a mail with Arabic content from a gmail id to another Gmail id. The Charset encoding type of the mail is windows-1256.  When i download the mail using Javamail I am getting content in "??????" format instead of Arabic Characters. I am converting the downloaded content to UTF-8 format but still not getting the proper display.

Thanks in advance,

Tim

**Update:**
I am using the following code to fetch the content :

```
Object content = message.getContent(); 
if (message.isMimeType("text/html")  
      || message.isMimeType("text/plain")) { 
      Al = (String) content; 
}
```

Once content is downloaded, the following code is used for UTF-8 encoding:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
s = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
```

**Update : Complete code that I am using for reading the mail contents at present**

```
String gmailMultipartMailDownload(Multipart multipart, String Uids)
        throws SocketException, UnsupportedDataTypeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String Content = new String("");        
    try {
        int numParts = multipart.getCount();            
        for (int k = 0; k < numParts; k++)
        {
            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(k);
            Object tmp = null;
            try 
            {
                tmp = bodyPart.getContent();
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedDataTypeException UEE)
            {
                try {
                    InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MessagingException e) {                        
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException UEE) {
                UEE.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MessagingException e) {                    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   

            String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

            if (tmp instanceof InputStream) {                   
                try{
                    if( super.Downloadfiles(bodyPart, hashCode, attnumcount,this.getgmailattachmentfolder()))
                    {                       
                        //Download Attachments
                    }
                }catch (FileNotFoundException err) {                     
                    return Content;
                }
                catch(IOException fex){                  
                    fex.printStackTrace();
                    return Content;
                }
            }
            else if (disposition != null
                    && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT) || disposition.equals(BodyPart.INLINE) || disposition.equals("ATTACHMENT"))) {

                 try{
                     if( super.Downloadfiles(bodyPart, hashCode, attnumcount,this.getgmailattachmentfolder()))
                {

                        //Download Attachments
                }
                 }catch (FileNotFoundException err) {

                 System.out.println(err.getMessage());
                 return Content;
                 }
                 catch(IOException fex){         

                 fex.printStackTrace();
                 return Content;}
            } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) bodyPart.getContent();               

                Content += gmailMultipartMailDownload(mp, Uids);

            } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {                  

                Content += bodyPart.getContent().toString();                    
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception Ex) {      
        System.out.println("Content object  error is  "+Ex);            
        return Content;         
    } finally {
        return Content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that is doing the fetching and decoding, and explain how you are displaying the problematic characters.

Comment: I am using the following code to fetch the content  :         Object content = message.getContent();
if (message.isMimeType("text/html")     || message.isMimeType("text/plain"))                        {
 Al = (String) content;

}                                                                   Once content is downloaded, the following code is used for UTF-8 encoding:                                         
byte[] utf8Bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
s = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");

Comment: About displaying the content, I am trying to display it on the browser window at present since I am testing my code now.   This issue happens only when i send mail from a Gmail Id to another gmail Id.  When I send mail from Thunderbird or any other mail client to another Gmail Id, it works perfectly and displaying the arabic content

Comment: Are you saying you encounter the problem only when sending email using Gmail's web mail? What if you send your email using Thunderbird throw Gmail?

Comment: Yes, When i send mail from Gmail to Gmail, then content is displayed in ??? format.  The default character set for this mail is windows-1256.  When i send mail from another email account using Thunderbird to the same Gmail id, then the content is displaying properly. The character set for this mail is ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me:

```
public boolean sendEmail(String sender, String recipient, String subject, String body)
    {
        try
        {
            // set properties of mail server
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.setProperty("charset","utf-8");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

            // connect to mail server
            javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator()
            {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                { return new PasswordAuthentication(gmailUser,gmailPassword);   }  
            });

            // create email
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
            message.setContent(body, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));

            // send email
            Transport.send(message);

            return true;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          System.out.println("Exception thown "+e.getMessage());
          return false;
       }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to execute the code.  But getting Exception   javax.mail.IllegalWriteException: IMAPMessage is read-only.

Comment: Message mails=null;
   try {
     mails = folder.getMessage(i);
    } catch (MessagingException e1) {     
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {                 
              mails.setContent(headers, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
              mails.saveChanges();                   
               } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
                }

Comment: And for connecting to gmail server   public void getgmailConecction() {
  try {
   Properties props = System.getProperties();
   props.setProperty("charset","utf-8");
   props.setProperty("mail.mime.decodeparameters", "true");
   props.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "true");
   session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
   this.setSession(session);
   SetSessionDebug(session);
   gmailStore = session.getStore(gmailProtocol);
   gmailStore.connect(gmailHost, gmailPort, gmailUser, gmailPassword);
  } catch (Exception Ex) {
   System.out.println(Ex);   
  }
 }

Comment: try to use this instead: MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

Comment: still no hope... When i send mail from my personal mail using thunder bird client to Gmail, it downloads and displays correctly.  Only when i send mail which contains arabic content from Gmail to Gmail is the issue.

Comment: The code which you posted is to send the mail using Gmail. But my problem is with reading the mail content using Javamail.  This code is working fine for me for sending the mail.  But i am getting error when i try to read the content using javamail.

Comment: so if you open your gmail you can see the emails ok there ?

Comment: Yes.. When i access Gmail directly, I am able to read the messages.

Comment: try this:if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                    Multipart c = ((Multipart)content);
                    BodyPart p = c.getBodyPart(0);
                    messageText = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"); }

Comment: Hi Yael... Still not working... am getting the content as ???? ????????? ????????

Comment: the connection code: Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            props.setProperty("charset","utf-8");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "user", "pw");

Comment: Hi Yael, I think there is no problem with the connection properties.  All other mails are getting downloaded properly and even the arabic content mail which i send from my office mail using Thunderbird client to the same Gmail id for testing.  The problem happens only when i send mails from Gmail to Gmail with Arabic  or any other language content except English

Comment: @Timson If you've got a working solution that differs from the answer above, you should post it as a new answer rather than editing this one. If you merely want to post code to discuss, edit your question. Thanks and welcome to SO

Comment: I'm Sorry for that.  It was not an answer.  Just tried to update the code which i am using at present and which giving me the error

Comment: the whole code will be very useful, if needed open another question and post a comment here to direct to there

Comment: cng to this IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"); u just have p.getInputStream();

Comment: Yes, i have tried my code with IOUtils from commons.  But it was not working for me.  The code which i posted is my original code.

Comment: I my code,  Content += bodyPart.getContent().toString() fetch the mail content and stores it in a string. This code works fine if the mail content is in English.  If the content is in some other languages like Arabic and if it is send from one Gmail Id to another Gmail Id, this code is not working.  If i send the mail from my office email using Thunder bird client to the same Gmail id, this code works fine.

Comment: When is use IOUtils instead of bodyPart.getContent().toString(), I am getting the content as same as  ??? format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something linke this:

```
protected static String readContent(Part part) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    return new String(part.getContent().toString().getBytes(), readCharset(part.getContentType()));
}

/**
 * Read charset from ContentType of javax.mail.internet.Part (MimePart, BodyPart, etc).
 * eg: "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
 * The result: Charset ISO-8859-1
 *
 * @param contentType content-type like "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
 * @return Charset
 */
protected static Charset readCharset(String contentType) {
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(contentType)) {
        String[] _split = contentType.split("charset=");
        if (_split != null && _split.length == 2) {
            String _c = _split[1];
            try {
                charset = Charset.forName(_c);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Invalid content-type charset: " + contentType);
            }
        }
    }

    return charset;
}
```

It's not the best solution, but it works.

Regards,
Pedro Sousa

Answer (score 0):

message.setContent(content+"","text/html; charset=utf-8");

you need to add this line, for arabic.

Answer (score 0):

the one which worked for me,

```
String utf8EncodedString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```