# recipient getting question marks instead of Arabic text on email messages

Tags: android, gmail

I am trying to send e-mail in Android using the JavaMail API using Gmail authentication , but the  recipient getting question marks"????????" instead of Arabic text on email messages . Is it a Unicode problem or what?
how do I send text messages that don't appear as question marks at the recipient?

I am applying this example
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

thanks in advance,,,

Comment: This must be encoding issue, Android system support unicode, where as the content (arabic) you are using in the project maybe ascii or other. If you used any MS-office product in editing/creating content, then I can confirm this is encoding issue, because office file are NOT in unicode.

Comment: Are you using a file or web request for your arabic content?

Comment: I have found the Solution In this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407922/arabic-content-issue-in-reading-mails-using-javamail-api

Comment: Are you getting proper arabic letters in gmail??.. when i am sending using webservice even I am getting questions.. @NawalSalameh